# Constrain Flutter ripple effect to text field with rounded border

Tags: flutter

I've been trying to get the ripple effect to work correctly in a TextField with rounded borders. In the sample code, there are two text fields, both with issues. In the top field, the ripple effect is not confined to the rounded border; it extends out to the rectangular bounds of the widget, as shown here (please ignore the green circle):

[image]

The second widget attempts to address this by surrounding the field with a `Material` and `ClipRRect`. This partially works, and ordinarily correctly confines the ripple effect to the border of the component. However, when validation fails, and the validation error is shown, the rendering is messed up by the clipping:

[image]

Is there any way to get the ripple effect to correctly stay within the text field border in all circumstances?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(inputDecorationTheme: _theme()),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              _textField(),
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                child: Material(
                  child: _textField(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  InputDecorationTheme _theme() => ThemeData.light().inputDecorationTheme.copyWith(
        errorBorder: _makeRoundedInputBorder(),
        enabledBorder: _makeRoundedInputBorder(),
        focusedBorder: _makeRoundedInputBorder(),
        focusedErrorBorder: _makeRoundedInputBorder(),
      );

  OutlineInputBorder _makeRoundedInputBorder() =>
      OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40)));

  TextFormField _textField() => TextFormField(
        validator: (value) => value.length > 5 ? "Can't have more than five characters" : null,
        autovalidate: true,
      );
}
```

Comment: have you tried using the normal text field, and encasing it inside a rounded container?

Comment: @JulienLachal have you got an example of what you had in mind?

Comment: try to replace the children of your `Column` by `Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)), child: _textField());`

Comment: @JulienLachal alas, that has the same behaviour as the first case, where the ripple effect overflows the rounded border.

Answer (score 3):

I used borderRadius and clipBehavior of Material and it works for me.

```html
Material(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
  child: _textField(),
)
```

Comment: This is working correctly and should be the accepted answer. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64934586/2385476) provided by [user7408943](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7408943/user7408943) is correct and working as desired. I am adding another example to improve the answer.

```
         return Material(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            elevation: 5,
            clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                printInfo(info: 'Sample data is coming!');
              },
              child: CachedNetworkImage(
                height: Adapt.height(73),
                width: Adapt.height(73),
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                imageUrl: announcement.imageAttachments[i].url,
                progressIndicatorBuilder: (c, t, p) {
                  return Center(
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 25,
                      width: 25,
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          );
```